# LaTeX formulas in answers of ARSnova system

Tags: r, r-exams

I'm using the R/Exams package to generate quizzes for the ARSnova platform, but I can not get the LaTeX formulas correctly displayed in the answers of the quizzes. The formulas are well displayed in the questions but not in the answers. I've tried with different math delimiters but none of them work. Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong. Unfortunately, the https://arsnova.eu/mobile/# server does not support LaTeX in the answer options. However, when setting up your own ARSnova installation, you can tweak the configuration to support this, see: https://github.com/thm-projects/arsnova-backend/blob/340bbed5011577a83fd06a9ee3bb2ceb9102d658/src/main/resources/arsnova.properties.example#L245

As the comments in that configuration file point out: Rendering of Markdown and/or MathJax (for LaTeX) might lead to display errors in some contexts. Apparently, they chose to disable that option by default.

Our university has its own ARSnova installation and was kind enough to enable this option. For me including LaTeX and Markdown formatting in the answer options has worked without a problem so far.

Comment: Thanks @achim for your answer!
I will open an issue in Github. 
Could you tell me which files should I tweak in order to enable Mathjax in the answers. 
Thanks again!

Comment: I've completely rewritten my response after talking to our IT support. It turns out that the ARSnova server can already be configured to support LaTeX in the answers. It's just that the official ARSnova server has switched it off while our unversity server has switched it on...